# Why is my player falling through the floor?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have just created a repository on Github with my project.

The problem I having is my player falls right through the floor. If I import `Standard Assets` and use theis first person character, This does not happen. I am assuming it is an issue of using vectors, but I do not know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Identify Issue

It mostly happen when there is cno collider attached to the body but you try to
apply gravity to gameobject . The gameobject tries to move towards down due to the gravity but the collision helps that object to sustain on its place .

## Apply any of below solutions

1. Remove the gravity applied on the body
2. Attach the Collider that help the gameobject stopping it from falling it down
3. Check the x y and z axis as well. Click on the gameObject it will tell you its axis . Adjust your axis according to the logic you have applied

Comment: If you download the project in the link in my question, you will see that there is a collider on all objects in the scene. I used `CharacterController.Move()` snd that fixed my problem. Thanks for the answer, though.